# Flask/Threading - Pass data from model as arguments to a function

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

New to Python/Flask/Flask-SQLAlchemy.  I am trying to start a thread for each user to do something with their username/email.  I have been playing around with passing the model data to templates and using it there, but this has me stumped.

```
#Create the user model to store usernames & emails
class User(db.Model):
 id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
 username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
 email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

#Function to do something with the each users username & email
def do_something(name, email):
    #code goes here that does stuff with the name & email

#Query to get the list of all users data
users = User.query.all()

#Start threads for each user and pass in the users data (usernames & emails) to the do_something function
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(do_something, users.username, users.email)
```

I get the following error

```
executor.map(do_something, users.username, users.email)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'username'
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Seems the error comes not from this code^^

Comment: I know the error is coming from that code but why?  Why does it not pass the usernames & emails to the function?

Comment: I read 'posts.usernames' and I don't see it in the code sorry, and why use multiple thread ? Is that task hard ?

Comment: Sorry, the error was incorrect. I updated it.  This is just a simple example (using username & email) of what I am trying to do.  The actual function is quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

`users = User.query.all()` returns a **list** of all `Users`. A **list** does not have a `username` attribute. You need to loop over the list to get the `User` out.

Maybe something like this:

```
#Query to get the list of all users data
users = User.query.all()

#Start threads for each user and pass in the users data (usernames & emails) to the do_something function
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for user in users:
         executor.map(do_something, user.username, user.email)
```